# Change Link URL in preprocess function

Tags: 8, theming

I need to slightly modify some URLs that are in a "Link" field on a custom entity type.

In a `mytheme_preprocess_myentity` I've found that field with `$variables['elements']['field_my_url'][0]` I get this output in Kint

[image]

I've tried using a number of methods on the `#url` object but I don't think I'm doing it correctly... I'm just confused on how to modify it at this point.

How can I change the external URL to which this particular field is pointing?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal's Core Url has a static `fromUri()` method (see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x)

With that in mind you should be able to swap out the `['#url']` with a new one thusly:

```
...['#url'] = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('externalURL');
```